# What is difference between Element and RenderObject in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget, element

I am confusing between `Widget` and `Element` and `RenderObject` in Flutter. As I know, UI displayed on the screen is `Element`, a `Widget` is only a blueprint.

The document says: An Element is an instantiation of a Widget at a particular location in the tree. So, A Widget is a Dart class and an Element is an instance of this class, right?

So, Can I imagine them like the image below?

[image: Widget and Element]

But, I read [this article](https://www.didierboelens.com/2019/09/flutter-internals/?fbclid=IwAR1s-dcp-SffTC_LxDDg4oXos3N_Y8-ZFI4sLKJ40n7RuzU4CIJW1Xp58Bc) and I see UI displayed on the screen is `RenderObject`, not `Element`.So, I am confusing between `Widget` and `Element` and `RenderObject`. The real Lamborghini on my image is RenderObject or Element?

[image: Widget and RenderObject]

Answer (score 2):

> So, A Widget is a Dart class and an Element is an instance of this class, right?

Well, `Widget` and `Element` are both Dart classes.

When the Doc says *'instantiation'*, it didn't mean making an instance from a class.

It means, as you mentioned, `Widget` is some kind of a blueprint(hold some information), and `Element` is some other stuff that's made from the corresponding `Widget`.

`Widget` makes `Element`, and that `Element` makes `RenderObject` (by using Widget's method).

And `RenderObject` is the actual thing that is used for rendering stuff onto the screen.

> The real Lamborghini on my image is RenderObject or Element?

So, the Lamborghini on your image is made from `RenderObject`, of course `Widget` and `Element` are also used behind the scenes.